# After booting into Debian 8 my VGA monitor goes black?

Tags: debian, boot, monitors

After I installed Debian 8 successfully on my machine (Intel Pentium CPU and no GPU ) and rebooted into `GRUB2` successfully my monitor goes black  (Still on) after it boots into Debian I can hear my machine work.

I have an old monitor with VGA input. After doing research I found several solutions but they either did not work, or I didn't set them correctly. I have tried adding `video=LVDS-1:d` to the kernel and adding `GRUB_GFXMODE=1600x900` but nothing happened.

**PS:** I used `Live CD 32 bit` to install `Debian`, I've using the live CD to boot into `Debian` but the same problem exists.

Comment: This is an old question, but if you still have the problem, please post the X logs.